# Getting TypeError doc.sheetsByTitle is not a function, google-spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm, google-sheets-api

I'm using 'google-spreadsheet' and I'm successfully creating a new worksheet but for some reason, I can't manipulate or even select it. I searched through the docs and sites but I still couldn't find a solution.

```
async function startup () {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(config.sheetID);

    let creds = require('login data')

    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);

    await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
    console.log(doc.title);

    for (var i = 0; i < config.channelID.length; i++) {
        doc.addSheet({ title: config.channelID[i] })

        let sheet = await doc.sheetsByTitle(config.channelID[i])
        
    }
}
```

`(node:50552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: doc.sheetsByTitle is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the script of "node-google-spreadsheet", it seems that `doc.sheetsByTitle` returns an object. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/b2275eba33616e880c8fea376a32561e2cec4ea0/lib/GoogleSpreadsheet.js) I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (var i = 0; i < config.channelID.length; i++) {
    doc.addSheet({ title: config.channelID[i] })

    let sheet = await doc.sheetsByTitle(config.channelID[i])
    
}
```

#### To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < config.channelID.length; i++) {
  await doc.addSheet({ title: config.channelID[i] });
  let sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle[config.channelID[i]];
  console.log(sheet.title);  // You can check the added sheet name here.
}
```

Or, in your case, `doc.addSheet` also returns the sheet object. So you can use the following script.

```
for (var i = 0; i < config.channelID.length; i++) {
  const addedSheet = await doc.addSheet({ title: config.channelID[i] });
  console.log(addedSheet.title);  // You can check the added sheet name here.
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, please use `await` to `doc.addSheet`.
- Please use the latest version of node-google-spreadsheet. Now, it seems that it's `google-spreadsheet@3.0.13`.

#### Reference:

- [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)